# Embedding MPMoviePlayerController in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am embedding an instance of an MPMoviePlayerController in a tableViewCell for a chat app. The Movie Player works great until another cell is created; the screen then turns black and the video can no longer be reproduced. After instantiating an MPMoviePlayerController, I call the prepareToPlay method, I give it a frame, I set its scalingMode to MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit, and I add it to a view in the cell. The view's frame is the same as the MPMoviePlayerController's view property.
What must I do to allow my video to be playable after another cell is created ?

Answer (score 0):

When next cell is created `MPMoviePlayerController` is trying to play another video because for each new cell `MPMoviePlayerController` instance is created and video will start to playing.

How ever the fact is that `MPMoviePlayerController` can only play single video at a time.

See the [**Apple documentation:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

> **NOTE**
>
> Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.

You can definitely do this I mean play multiple videos in each cell by using **[AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer)**

A good git repository (**[MyVideoPlayer](https://github.com/cezarsignori/MyVideoPlayer)**) will also help to make it easier.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! I don't need to have the videos playing at the same time. What i want is for the user to be able to hit play on one video and then once that video ends to be able to hit play in another cell, but the play button disappears once a new cell is created and all i'm left with is a black view. Do you know how to keep the buttons and make the video playable after other cells are created.